# How to encode a long in Base64 in Python?

Tags: python, base64

In Java, I can encode a `BigInteger` as:

```
java.math.BigInteger bi = new java.math.BigInteger("65537L");
String encoded = Base64.encodeBytes(bi.toByteArray(), Base64.ENCODE|Base64.DONT_GUNZIP);

// result: 65537L encodes as "AQAB" in Base64

byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(encoded, Base64.DECODE|Base64.DONT_GUNZIP);
java.math.BigInteger back = new java.math.BigInteger(decoded);
```

In C#:

```
System.Numerics.BigInteger bi = new System.Numerics.BigInteger("65537L");
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64(bi);
byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded);
System.Numerics.BigInteger back = new System.Numerics.BigInteger(decoded);
```

How can I encode long integers in Python as Base64-encoded strings? What I've tried so far produces results different from implementations in other languages (so far I've tried in Java and C#), particularly it produces longer-length Base64-encoded strings.

```
import struct
encoded = struct.pack('I', (1<<16)+1).encode('base64')[:-1]
# produces a longer string, 'AQABAA==' instead of the expected 'AQAB'
```

When using this Python code to produce a Base64-encoded string, the resulting decoded integer in Java (for example) produces instead `16777472` in place of the expected `65537`. Firstly, what am I missing?

Secondly, I have to figure out by hand what is the length format to use in `struct.pack`; and if I'm trying to encode a long number (greater than `(1<<64)-1`) the `'Q'` format specification is too short to hold the representation. Does that mean that I have to do the representation by hand, or is there an undocumented format specifier for the `struct.pack` function? (I'm not compelled to use `struct`, but at first glance it seemed to do what I needed.)

Comment: im assuming that it has something to do with padding the python output is padded while C# and java is not padded

Comment: @SaddamAbuGhaida Yes, the binary representation of `struct.pack` has trailing `\x00` characters which yield the extra padding. Does that mean that I have to trim the extra padding manually?

Comment: yes you need to strip it

Comment: you have your `<<` the wrong way round

Comment: Try looking at the numbers in hex: `hex(16777472)` is `0x1000100`, while `hex(65537)` is `0x10001`. Does that help you figure out what's going on?

Comment: @gnibbler Thanks, I've fixed it. BTW, surely you know that above a certain number of points you can edit other people's posts. I wouldn't have minded if you'd take the initiative to fix it, but I appreciate that you pointed it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

> … performs conversions between Python values and C structs represented as Python strings.

Because C doesn't have infinite-length integers, there's no functionality for packing them.

But it's very easy to write yourself. For example:

```
def pack_bigint(i):
    b = bytearray()
    while i:
        b.append(i & 0xFF)
        i >>= 8
    return b
```

Or:

```
def pack_bigint(i):
    bl = (i.bit_length() + 7) // 8
    fmt = '<{}B'.format(bl)
    # ...
```

And so on.

And of course you'll want an `unpack` function, like jbatista's from the comments:

```
def unpack_bigint(b):
    b = bytearray(b) # in case you're passing in a bytes/str
    return sum((1 << (bi*8)) * bb for (bi, bb) in enumerate(b))
```

Comment: Thanks! With your first example, I'm able to do something such as: `bi = bytes(pack_bigint(i));` `b64bi = base64.standard_b64encode(bi);`

Comment: @jbatista: Doesn't `base64.standard_b64encode` work directly on `bytearray`, so you don't need the `bytes` conversion? Or is that only in 3.x?

Comment: I've tried in Python 2.6.6. `base64.standard_b64encode` doesn't work with a `bytearray` (it produces a `TypeError`), but it works if I previously surround with a `bytes()` around the returning `bytearray`.

Comment: @jbatista: Aha, it looks like that was added in 2.7 and 3.2. OK, then, explicit `bytes` it is. Glad you figured that out without a problem.

Comment: To complement your answer: `def unpack_bigint(b): n=0L; for bi,bb in enumerate(b): n+=(1<<(bi*8))*ord(bb); return n;`

Comment: @jbatista: Yeah, I probably should have given one `pack` and one `unpack`, instead of 1-1/2 `pack`s… I'll add yours to the answer. But you might as well use `bytearray` again, so you don't need the `ord` on each character. (If you have _huge_ bigints, this might be wasteful—but then the OP is already converting the `bytearray` from `pack` into a `bytes`.)

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I thought it would be worth mentioning that this code provides a byte array encoded using little-endianness (i.e. the least significant bytes will be stored at the beginning of the array), since append() adds a new byte at the end of the byte array, and we're inserting bytes that are more and more significant. If you want big-endianness,  you can, for instance return b.reverse() in pack_bigint(), and also perform a b.reverse() before the return statement in unpack_bigint()

Answer (score 7):

Check out this page on [converting integer to base64](http://fuyun.org/2009/10/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-base64-in-python/).

```
import base64
import struct

def encode(n):
    data = struct.pack('<Q', n).rstrip('\x00')
    if len(data)==0:
        data = '\x00'
    s = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(data).rstrip('=')
    return s

def decode(s):
    data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(s + '==')
    n = struct.unpack('<Q', data + '\x00'* (8-len(data)) )
    return n[0]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for numbers larger than `1<<63`, which the OP specifically asked for.

Comment: The code doesn't work as-is.  However, if you change `'x00'` to `'\x00'` it works.  I think the blog software processed away his backslashes.  Those are supposed to be constants for char 0.  You could also put `chr(0)` there.

Comment: @msc Gah! I didn't know about `rstrip`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but I figured I'd throw my hat in the ring:

```
def inttob64(n):                                                              
    """                                                                       
    Given an integer returns the base64 encoded version of it (no trailing ==)
    """
    parts = []                                                                
    while n:                                                                  
        parts.insert(0,n & limit)                                             
        n >>= 32                                                              
    data = struct.pack('>' + 'L'*len(parts),*parts)                           
    s = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(data).rstrip('=')                            
    return s                                                                  

def b64toint(s):                                                              
    """                                                                       
    Given a string with a base64 encoded value, return the integer representation
    of it                                                                     
    """                                                                       
    data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(s + '==')                                 
    n = 0                                                                     
    while data:                                                               
        n <<= 32                                                              
        (toor,) = struct.unpack('>L',data[:4])                                
        n |= toor & 0xffffffff                                                
        data = data[4:]                                                       
    return n
```

These functions turn an arbitrary-sized long number to/from a big-endian base64 representation.

Comment: I assume "limit" in inttob64 is 0xffffffff?

Answer (score 1):

[`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) added after Python 3.2

```python
import base64

def int_to_b64(n: int) -> str:
    bytes_length = (n.bit_length() + 7) // 8
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(n.to_bytes(bytes_length, 'big')).decode().rstrip('=')

def b64_to_int(b64: str) -> int:
    data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(b64 + '==')
    return int.from_bytes(data, 'big')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may help.  Instead of using `struct.pack()` I am building a string of bytes to encode and then calling the BASE64 encode on that.  I didn't write the decode, but clearly the decode can recover an identical string of bytes and a loop could recover the original value.  I don't know if you need fixed-size integers (like always 128-bit) and I don't know if you need Big Endian so I left the decoder for you.

Also, `encode64()` and `decode64()` are from @msc's answer, but modified to work.

```
import base64
import struct

def encode64(n):
  data = struct.pack('<Q', n).rstrip('\x00')
  if len(data)==0:
    data = '\x00'
  s = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(data).rstrip('=')
  return s

def decode64(s):
  data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(s + '==')
  n = struct.unpack('<Q', data + '\x00'* (8-len(data)) )
  return n[0]

def encode(n, big_endian=False):
    lst = []
    while True:
        n, lsb = divmod(n, 0x100)
        lst.append(chr(lsb))
        if not n:
            break
    if big_endian:
        # I have not tested Big Endian mode, and it may need to have
        # some initial zero bytes prepended; like, if the integer is
        # supposed to be a 128-bit integer, and you encode a 1, you
        # would need this to have 15 leading zero bytes.
        initial_zero_bytes = '\x00' * 2
        data = initial_zero_bytes + ''.join(reversed(lst))
    else:
        data = ''.join(lst)
    s = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(data).rstrip('=')
    return s

print encode(1234567890098765432112345678900987654321)
```